# How do they do this? Modal bookmarklet and instant scraping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simple-html-dom

I want a user to open a pop up window from a bookmarklet, but the page loads in like a jquery modal - meaning no ugly browser borders.

See example here, how are Amazon doing this?

http://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/get-button

Also, they are obviously scraping the page to get the info but the page load is almost instant, are they caching every page a user reads somehow? How else would they achieve this? I've tried simple-html-dom but it is far from instant

This is the JS Amazon use:

```
javascript:(function(){var w=window,l=w.location,d=w.document,s=d.createElement('script'),e=encodeURIComponent,o='object',n='AUWLBookenGB',u='https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add',r='readyState',T=setTimeout,a='setAttribute',g=function(){d[r]&&d[r]!='complete'?T(g,200):!w[n]?(s[a]('charset','UTF-8'),s[a]('src',u+'.js?loc='+e(l)+'&b='+n),d.body.appendChild(s),f()):f()},f=function(){!w[n]?T(f,200):w[n].showPopover()};typeof s!=o?l.href=u+'?u='+e(l)+'&t='+e(d.title):g()}())
```

[Beautified](http://jsbeautifier.org) and manually deobfuscated:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var w = window,
        l = w.location,
        d = w.document,
        s = d.createElement('script'),
        e = encodeURIComponent,
        o = 'object',
        n = 'AUWLBookenGB',
        u = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add',
        r = 'readyState',
        T = setTimeout,
        a = 'setAttribute',
        g = function() {
            if (d[r] && d[r] != 'complete') {
                T(g, 200);
            } else if(!w[n]) {
                s[a]('charset', 'UTF-8');
                s[a]('src', u + '.js?loc=' + e(l) + '&b=' + n);
                d.body.appendChild(s);
                f();
            } else {
                f();
            }
        },
        f = function() {
            if (!w[n]) {
                T(f, 200);
            } else {
                w[n].showPopover();
            }
    };
    if (typeof s != o) {
        l.href = u + '?u=' + e(l) + '&t=' + e(d.title);
    } else {
        g();
    }
}())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly de-obfuscated the code, see the question’s post.

The script requests a script from amazon's website, with the following URL:

```
https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add.js?loc=<CURRENT URL>&b=AUWLBookenGB
```

Inside the response's code ([add.js example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add.js?loc=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9453472%2Fhow-do-they-do-this-modal-bookmarklet-and-instant-scraping&b=AUWLBookenGB)), a `<table>` element is dynamically created and populated, then inserted in the page.

The "magic" happens at the server's side, where the script is generated. All necessary data is served with the injected JS file.

Answer (score 1):

That javascript code creates a `<script>` tag to load up the js file (needed to create a wishlist popup) into the page you are on.

```
http://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add.js?loc=your-page-url&b=AUWLBookenGB:1703
```

The above url does not take much time to load the js file into the page which eventually creates a popup. Finally it hits the amazon server to load the popup dynamically by visiting the following url.

```
https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add?u=your-page-url&t=your-page-title
```

The secret is how fast can you load the content needed to generate a popup so it should load instantly.

Comment: codef0rmer - question is, what is the secret? Is it caching? I think not as this would prove impossible with a multi-tabbed browser - I checked it with a page I loaded BEFORE I added the bookmarklet and it was still almost instant

Comment: I mean the secret is nothing but to push the necessary data to client side as fast as possible. It could be caching, fast servers or CDN stuff. How was it when you try to run similar thing locally?

Comment: The fastest I can get it to happen using a standard web page pop up and then extracting images etc using simple-html-dom is about 4-5 seconds - which in todays world is a long, long time

Comment: can you post your code here How you extract images and stuff? For me the amazon popup took 6 seconds to show up (with 6 images) on my webpage.

Comment: This is the post i did a while ago which shows it all - didn't really get a good answer - the amazon one for me is almost always instant which is weird: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980519/how-can-i-speed-this-up

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit difficult to read but this is basically what it does:

- create a `<script>` in the current document (the page you are currently viewing) and set its source to https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add.js
- the script executes and actually create a `AUWLBookenGB` object to the global scope
- then the method `showPopover();` is executed with `w[n].showPopover();` which actually correspond to `window.AUWLBookenGB.showPopover();

The method `showPopover()` is responsible for showing the popup.